# How can I remove not a first occurrence in the list?

Tags: python, list

So I have a couple lists which look like this:
lst = [1, 3, 1, 1] and lst2 = [3]

I need to remove "1" from the lst, but a specific "1": lst[2] and I need to insert the "3" from lst2 into that particular spot.

Remove doesn`t really help, because it removes the first occurrence.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention making your question clear and to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Can you describe the general form of your problem? You are not helping us very much with that one specific example

Answer (score 0):

You can use del to delete element at given index in python. To insert element at specific position, you can use in insert(index, element). In your case, following will work:

```
lst = [1, 3, 1, 1]
lst2 = [3]
del lst[2] #This will delete element at position 2 from lst list
lst.insert(2,3) #This will insert element 3 at position 2 in lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst=[int(input("Enter a number into the list: "))]
lstcopy=lst
while True:
    new=input("Enter one more number into the list: ")
    if not new:
        break
    lst.append(int(new))
findMe=int(input("Enter the number to find: "))
findMeOccurence=int(input("Enter the occurence number of "+str(findMe)+" that you want to find: "))
idx=-1
error=False
try:
    for i in range(findMeOccurence):
        idx+=1
        lstcopy=lstcopy[idx:]
        idx=lstcopy.index(findMe)
except:
    print("Your number does not exist at that occurence.")
    error=True
if not error:
    del lst[idx+1]
    print("\nThis is your list with "+str(findMe)+" removed at occurence "+str(findMeOccurence)+":\n"+str(lst))
```

What this does is get your list (you can preset it and remove the list getting code), make a copy of it in `lstcopy`, get the number to find (again you can preset), and the position to find it (presetting is possible here, too).  Then it sets `idx` to `-1` and `error` to `False`.  Inside the `try`, a loop is done that:

1. Increases `idx` by 1
2. Cuts `lstcopy` so that the next step doesn't do this recursively
3. Use `index` to get the new `idx`.

`index` raises an exception when it cannot find the given item, and that will be caught with the `except`, saying that your number doesn't exist (because the loop hadn't finished yet, so the occurrence was not found).  Then it sets `error` to `True`.

At the ending part, it checks for `error` to be `False` (because by default it was `False` and we are using the `not` keyword), and if so, that means the error message ("Your number does not exist at that occurence.") has not been given, so delete the index using `del lst[idx+1]` and show the user the new list.  This is the reason `lstcopy` was made: because at the end, it needs the full `lst` to `del` from, not the cut up `lstcopy` from that loop!

I have tried this with Python 3.8.1, try it yourself and tell me in the comments if it worked!